# Something Wrong when I was building the scala project using IntelliJ IDEA 14 on the Mac OX 10.10

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

Today, When I restart the machine, it works. But after several compiling, it's down again, and I should restart the machine. So strange, anyone who can fix it. Many Thanks!

This is the project structure
[image]

This is the simple test code:

```
/**
 * Created by sunji on 15/11/3.
 */
object hello {
  def main(arg: Array[String]): Unit={
    System.out.println("hello world!")
  }
}
```

And this is the error information

```
Error:Internal error: (java.io.EOFException) null
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Chunk$.readFrom(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:92)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.handle(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.handle(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:30)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.send(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.send(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.compile(RemoteServer.scala:17)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:47)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:41)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:535)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:40)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:39)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$.compile(ScalaBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.IdeaIncrementalBuilder.build(IdeaIncrementalBuilder.scala:73)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1196)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:877)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:945)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:840)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:663)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:370)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:191)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:293)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:242)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/451909

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jdk 1.8. It is working for me.